# How to unpack a zip file and import smth from it as part of the build?

Tags: msbuild

Is there a way to modify msbuild project file in such way that during build (as first step) following happens:

- given zip file is unpacked to target location (unless that location already has been populated)
- certain `.target` file is imported from aforementioned directory

?

I.e. something along the lines of a "poor man's Nuget"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding 1:
There's an [Unzip task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/unzip-task?view=vs-2019) in recent MSBuild versions:

```
    <Unzip
      SourceFiles="the\archive.zip"
      DestinationFolder="target\folder"
      Condition="!Exists('target\folder\expectedfile.props')"/>
```

(Note that this work extremely well with [DownloadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/downloadfile-task?view=vs-2019))

Regarding 2:

I suggest you split your build process into a `Restore` task that performs the download. Either create a `Restore` target in a CI project file or extend the restore process in csproj files (`<Target Name="Foo" AfterTargets="CollectPackageReferences">`).

Then only use `msbuild -r` (`dotnet msbuild -r build.proj`) or commands that implicitly restore (`dotnet build`, `dotnet pack` etc.) so that MSBuild will execute the restore and then clear its XML project file caches that otherwise would not be cleaned. This is important if the file contents change between different runs.

When importing files, check for avilability:

```
<Import Project="target\folder\expectedfile.props" Condition="Exists('target\folder\expectedfile.props')" />
```

Comment: I used `BeforeTargets="PrepareProjectReferences"` (because `CollectPackageReferences` target isn't built for some reason), but I am getting a problem with `Import` -- looks like `Condition` gets evaluated before `Unzip` is finished -- i.e. importing never happens. Can you help? (project is built in Visual Studio)

Comment: can you fix spelling in `CollectPackageRefereces`?

Comment: Corrected it, all restore paths in recent VS version should call into that - both CLI and VS.

Comment: Imports are always evaluated on the first parsing pass (1. global properties and imports, 2. item definitions, 3. items and then the build with targets starts).
This is why I suggest using `-r`: msbuild will spin off two separate builds for restore and actual build so the evaluation passes of the second build will see the import.

Comment: Does it mean it is impossible to have a setup where pressing F7 in Visual Studio will unpack `targets` file and then import it (in some project file)? Maybe it is possible to use same hook Nuget uses for restoring packages?

Comment: That is exactly what I suggest here by implementing the target that does this as `AfterTargets="CollectPackageReferences"`. That way VS will download and unpack during automatic restore and the file should be there for the normal build.

Comment: Hmm... It doesn't work for my C++ projects -- `CollectPackageReferences` never gets built (and mine too). :-\ VS 2017

Comment: I suspect, since my project doesn't have `packages.config` -- none of NuGet machinery in `...\NuGet.targets` get invoked and therefore `CollectPackageReferences`/`Restore`/etc target isn't even get pulled in.

Comment: In other words, for some reason `automatic restore` step never gets executed by VS...

Comment: Try `<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>`, but AFAIK C++ projects aren't supported with PackageReference by NuGet. You may be better off using NuGet packages to distribute those targets. Also you shouldn't need any of `NuGet.targets` / nuget.exe files in the projects since NuGet is always integrated in 2017+

Comment: Yeah, I tried that with no luck and already found all this info. I actually ended up using nugets for distribution (of my `vcpkg` bundle -- thankfully, `vcpkg` can generate proper nugets nowadays). But problem with nugets is that they have to be applied to all projects, solution-level packages are no longer supported. And since C++ projects can't use `PackageReference` -- I can't put single reference into a single`props` file used by all projects. Updating this bundle means changing a lot of files. It is not ideal... :-\