# F# SQL type provider sample: `dotnet build` works, but VS fails

Tags: visual-studio, f#, npgsql, visual-studio-2022, type-providers

I'm having a hard time understanding why this very basic sample of **F#** type providers (using the [SqlProvider nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLProvider)) builds fine in Windows in the command line but in VS2022 it doesn't:

https://github.com/knocte/FSharpSqlProviderSample

As you can see, [compilation in GitHubCI (in Ubuntu Linux)](https://github.com/knocte/FSharpSqlProviderSample/blob/master/.github/workflows/CI.yml) works [too](https://github.com/knocte/FSharpSqlProviderSample/runs/5688043187?check_suite_focus=true).

The errors are:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: BackendDataLayer, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Users\knocte\Documents\Code\FSharpSqlProviderSample\BackendDataLayer\Access.fs(15,9): error FS3033: The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider' reported an error: The type initializer for 'Npgsql.TypeMapping.BuiltInTypeHandlerResolver' threw an exception.
1>C:\Users\knocte\Documents\Code\FSharpSqlProviderSample\BackendDataLayer\Access.fs(15,9): error FS3033: The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider' reported an error: The type initializer for 'Npgsql.TypeMapping.BuiltInTypeHandlerResolver' threw an exception.
1>C:\Users\knocte\Documents\Code\FSharpSqlProviderSample\BackendDataLayer\Access.fs(18,23): error FS0039: The type 'Object' does not define the field, constructor or member 'GetDataContext'.
1>C:\Users\knocte\Documents\Code\FSharpSqlProviderSample\BackendDataLayer\Access.fs(22,26): error FS0072: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.
1>C:\Users\knocte\Documents\Code\FSharpSqlProviderSample\BackendDataLayer\Access.fs(23,28): error FS0072: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.
1>C:\Users\knocte\Documents\Code\FSharpSqlProviderSample\BackendDataLayer\Access.fs(23,38): error FS0072: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.
1>Done building project "BackendDataLayer.fsproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

To highlight the most important part of the code in the sample repository, this is the SqlDataProvider instantiation:

```
module Access =

    [<Literal>]
    let private connStr =
        "Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=runintomedb;User Id=postgres;Password='localDevPassword'"

    [<Literal>]
    let private resolutionPath = @"lib"

    type SQL =
        SqlDataProvider<Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.POSTGRESQL, connStr, Owner="public, admin, references", UseOptionTypes=true, ResolutionPath=resolutionPath>
```

And this is the resolutionPath tweaks I had to do to the .fsproj file (which, again, work fine when using `dotnet build` in the command line):

```
  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <MakeDir Directories="lib" />
    <Copy
        Condition="!Exists('lib\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll')"
        SourceFiles="..\packages\microsoft.bcl.asyncinterfaces\6.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll"
        DestinationFolder="lib"
    />
    <Copy
        Condition="!Exists('lib\Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode.dll')"
        SourceFiles="..\packages\microsoft.bcl.hashcode\1.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode.dll"
        DestinationFolder="lib"
    />
    <Copy
        Condition="!Exists('lib\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll')"
        SourceFiles="..\packages\system.threading.tasks.extensions\4.5.4\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll"
        DestinationFolder="lib"
    />
    <Copy
        Condition="!Exists('lib\System.Threading.Channels.dll')"
        SourceFiles="..\packages\system.threading.channels\6.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Threading.Channels.dll"
        DestinationFolder="lib"
    />
  </Target>
```

Comment: I don't have Postgres, so I modified this to use SQL Server's Northwind database instead. It built and runs fine, so I think the problem you're seeing might be specific to Postgres.

Comment: thanks for the info, I'll keep digging

Comment: maybe using `BeforeTargets="PrepareProjectReferences"` or `AfterTargets="CollectPackageReferences"` instead of  `BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent"` helps, I'm going to try that tomorrow (taken from the comments in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57307444/544947)